# SQL INSERT when two SELECTs return a not-null value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO combats (combat_killer, combat_victim, combat_weapon, combat_time, combat_server)
VALUES(
    (SELECT player_id FROM players WHERE player_username = 'Kvazos'),
    (SELECT player_id FROM players WHERE player_username = 'paulaagee'),
    'Diamond Sword',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    1
);
```

It will basically get the IDs of two other records and insert them into a table. However, there may be a case where the player_username sent does not exist and the SELECT will return NULL. **How can I prevent this INSERT from executing if one of the two SELECTs returns NULL?**

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The last sentence in bold specify that OP want to prevent from executing insert.

Comment: The query will already give me an exception if it fails. But the point here is not to have to get an exception thrown but to simply mark as query successful if there was no need to insert. @Jean-FrançoisSavard solved the question. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

```
INSERT INTO combats (combat_killer, combat_victim, combat_weapon, combat_time, combat_server)
SELECT a.player_id, b.player_id, 'Diamond Sword', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1
FROM (SELECT player_id from players where player_username = 'Kvazos') a
JOIN (SELECT player_id from players where player_username = 'paulaagee') b
WHERE a.player_id is not null
  AND b.player_id is not null;
```

Edit: added `1` after `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! I will mark as accepted answer when I can.

Note: You missed the combat_server value after the current_timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can express this query more simply as:

```
INSERT INTO combats(combat_killer, combat_victim, combat_weapon, combat_time, combat_server)
    SELECT a.player_id, b.player_id, 'Diamond Sword', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1
    FROM (SELECT player_id from players where player_username = 'Kvazos') a CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT player_id from players where player_username = 'paulaagee') b;
```

Neither a `where` nor `on` clause is needed.  If either query has no matches, then no rows are returned.